# vim mksession colorsheme issue

Tags: vim, gvim

I can sees that when I use mksession it writes file to save session. The file looks ok and session is loading ok. But It change my colorsheme when I load the session whith `so`. After session is opened the color scheme is another. What it can be? Why I cannot restore my session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@itun  The default behavior for VIM sessions is that it doesn't save off the colorscheme.  While I'm sure there is a good reason for doing this, I'm not sure what it is.

I have also run into the same situation, and wrote a couple of VIM functions and a VIM command to get the behavior you are talking about (really only needs to save off the :colorscheme colors_name).

```
" ===========================================================================
function! Mksession(...) " {{{
" Intercept the mksession built-in, so that we can append the current
" colorscheme to the setup as well.
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
"  call Dfunc("Mksession()")
```

" if argc() > 2
  "   echohl ErrorMsg
  "   echo "Command takes only 2 arguments, extra arguments ignored!"
  "   echohl None
  " endif

"  call Decho("a:0=<".a:0.">")
"  call Decho("a:1=<".a:1.">")
"  call Decho("a:2=<".a:2.">")
  " If no overwrite flag is supplied, assume no overwrite
  if a:1 == ""
    let l:overwrite = 0
  elseif a:1 == "!"
    let l:overwrite = 1
  endif

" If no session name is supplied, default to Session.vim in the current working directory
  if !exists("a:2") || a:2 == ""
  " if !exists("l:sessionname") || l:sessionname == ""
    let l:sessionname = "Session.vim"
  else
    let l:sessionname = a:2
  endif

"  call Decho("sessionname=<".l:sessionname.">")
"  call Decho("overwrite=<".l:overwrite.">")

if l:overwrite == 0
    exe "mksession ".l:sessionname
  else
    exe "mksession! ".l:sessionname
  endif
  silent exe '!echo colorscheme '.g:colors_name.' >> '.l:sessionname

"  call Dret("Mksession")
endfunction " Nodiff
com! -nargs=+ -bang -complete=command Mks  call Mksession("",)
cmap mks Mks
cmap mksession Mks
" }}}

This will create a VIM User command to wrap the built-in one (:Mks ), and also will add command-mode abbreviations to expand out the built-in command to use the new User Command version.

Hope that helps.